# Where should I call addBehavior for UIDynamicAnimator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics

I have a class called `DropitBehavior`, which is inherited from `UIDynamicBehavior`. And there are two properties in my `UIViewController`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DropitBehavior *dropitBehavior;
```

The lazy initializers are defined below. And the animation runs correctly.

```
- (UIDynamicAnimator *)animator
{
    if (!_animator) {
        _animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.gameView];
        //[_animator addBehavior:self.dropitBehavior];
    }

    return _animator;
}

- (DropitBehavior *)dropitBehavior
{
    if (!_dropitBehavior) {
        _dropitBehavior = [[DropitBehavior alloc] init];
        [self.animator addBehavior:_dropitBehavior];
    }

    return _dropitBehavior;
}
```

But if I call `addBehavior` in `animator` initializer, there will be no animation at all. As far as I understand, the animation should run in both ways. What's wrong with the second way?

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the getters for the `@property`'s, so judging from your code, the animator isn't created until you call it in the `dropitBehavior` method.

You would usually add behaviors to the animator in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` methods, so you know your views are ready to be animated. You code would look something like this:

```
- (UIDynamicAnimator *)animator {
    if (!_animator) {
        _animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.gameView];
    }
    return _animator;
}

- (DropitBehavior *)dropitBehavior {
    if (!_dropitBehavior) {
        _dropitBehavior = [[DropitBehavior alloc] init];
    }
    return _dropitBehavior;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];
    [self.animator addBehavior:self.dropitBehavior];
}
```

Comment: `dropitBehavior` is also a property. I think `animator` has been created after calling `alloc` and `init`.

Comment: It has, but only if the `.animator` property is used somewhere else. Otherwise `-(UIDynamicAnimator*)animator` method is never called, so `alloc` `init` are never executed

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want.